# find and replace line strings contained in one file to a second file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to find a solution to the following problem:

I have two files: i.e. file1 and file2. 
In file1 there some lines with some key words and I want to find these lines in file2 by using the key words. Once find the key words in file2 I would like to update this line with the content of the same line in file1. This operation should be done for every line contained in file1.

Just an example of what I have in mind, but I don't know exactly how to transform in shell script command.

```
file1:

key1=new_value1
key2=new_value2
key3=new_value3
etc....

file2:

key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
key4=value4
key5=value5
key6=value6
etc....


Result:

key1=new_value1
key2=new_value2
key3=new_value3
key4=value4
key5=value5
key6=value6
etc....
```

I don't know how can I use 'sed' or something else in shell script to accomplish this task.
Any help is welcomed.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk would be my first choice

```
awk -F= -v OFS== '
    NR==FNR {new[$1]=$2; next} 
    $1 in new {$2=new[$1]} 
    {print}
' file1 file2
```

Comment: very good piece of shell programming. Thank you it works flawlessly